# Google Analytics - Location Access Prompt displayed on accessing each site

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, microsoft-edge, google-geolocation

I am using Google Analytics script to triangulate the user location and their details when accessing a SharePoint Site.

We have added the Google Analytics script in the SharePoint site as an app.

A prompt is displayed "Let `<user>` use your location?" with Yes/No.

But in the Microsoft Edge user the prompt is displayed on each site even after the prompt is clicked yes.

For retrieving the location we are using the below script code,

```
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {    
                 let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                 let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            });
```

On using the above code the prompt appears.

My expectation is that to prevent the prompt when user access the site.

And is there a way we can add the site to some “approved site list” in Windows or the Browser so it doesn’t request.

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge version are you using? Please check your browser setting to allow cookies and JavaScript in order to use all the tools available in Analytics. You could refer [this article](https://support.qualityunit.com/022932-How-to-enable-cookies-in-Edge).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way of disabling prompt. Even if you specifically allow and remember location permission for every machine in your organization, it still can revoked easily via the menu in most major browsers.

Another way of achieving this is to check if location permission is given and then decide whether to initialize the app / block access to the app

```
function getLocation() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
  });
}

// then
(async function() {
  try {
    await getLocation();
    // got access
  } catch(e) {
    // no access
  }
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also I would like to know the frequency of the popup?  Only 1 time ever per user?  Once per browser session?  Once a day?

Comment: It differs from browser to browser. Chrome remembers your option while firefox require you to explicitly click to remember it. You could also make use of permission API, but safari doesn't support it yet, `navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(result => console.log(result.stste))`. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/permissions

Comment: Btw location can be easily faked on chrome